# appearance:button not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to style a link as if it was a button. This is the link:

```
<a class="link-as-button" id="logout" href="#">Log out</a>
```

The CSS style that is applied to it is:

```
.link-as-button {
  appearance: button; /* CSS3 */    
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-appearance: button; /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: button; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-appearance: button; /* Opera */
  cursor: default;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

Now this works perfectly in all the browsers except for IE (what a surprise). Tried a lot of stuff that I found on the internet but nothing helped. Microsoft's documentation states that they support -webkit-appearance property, but it looks like my IE totally disagrees with that. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry <br/> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp

Comment: Not supported by IE (as such) [**CanIUse,com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)

Comment: try adding !important after each line ie. `appearance: button !important;`

Comment: @Paulie_D https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says that they do support it

Comment: @MattyF didn't change anything. It's still a simple link with no style

Comment: @DannyPhantom was worth a try : )

Answer (score 0):

The Mozilla Development Network link [**HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) clarifies that the property is only supported in

> Internet Explorer (Windows Phone)  IE 11 on Windows Phone 8.1  -webkit-appearance (only the none, button, and textfield values)

It's worth pointing out that, regardless of support at present

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Also, [**Links are not Buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)